# How to determinante starting index of subarray in array in C

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C and I'm at the array and I'm having trouble solving the following problem:

> See if subarray is contained in the array and find it starting index.

Example :

```
ArrA[] = {1,3,5,2,7,6}, ArrB[] = {2,7}.
```

Output : Starting index of array B in array A is 3.

No need for completed code I just need an idea or suggestion on how to start.

Comment: `{5, 7}` is a "subarray" too. Does it count?

Comment: How would you do it on paper? Describe the steps in words first. Then progressively refine it into an algorithm that can be coded.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How is `{ 5, 7 }` a subarray of `ArrB`?

Comment: @Luc it is a subarray of ArrA, because it contains elements of it in the same order. Of course depends on the definition of "subarray"

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think you are confusing between subarray and subsequence/subset. In subarrays, the elements should be contiguous

Comment: Personally, I'd take the first index of `ArrB` as you're looking to match within `ArrA`, and cycle through each index, comparing the value of `ArrA[0]`. If you come across a match, check the next indexes of each array and compare to determine if the subarray is found. Storing the index of the first match.

Comment: @risingStark, Luc - looks like you are right. There is an unambiguous definition  of subarray.

Comment: [man 3 memcmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) will automate things, otherwise, nested loops will do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not at all. The `memcmp` function will tell you if two defined areas of a defined lengths have the same content. It certainly _will not_ tell you _whether_ and _where_ one string of data can be found within the other.

Comment: @CiaPan - you have just said the same thing I did. What do you not understand about the use of `memcmp` to determine if one array is the sub array of another. Is handling the beginning offset for comparison as you worth through the larger of the two giving you trouble?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Nope. What you said is 'memcmp will automate things'. And it won't, you still need to perform a manual iteration over possible starting indices of possible match. Using memcmp just lets you get rid of one nested loop. Additionally, it's a limited solution, as it only compares raw memory so it helps in simple cases like this, an array of well-aligning integers or similar. But take an array of `(char *)` and try to find same strings – and you'll fail. You need to compare strings by contents, not by location – using memcmp for arrays of pointers is futile.

Comment: @CiaPan You are inventing arguments that don't exist. Where do you find an array of pointers in this question?? It most certainly will automate this task. It eliminates the inner loop of the nested loop by comparing two-bytes at a time. What part of that do you not understand? You simply loop `0 < i < n - 2` where `n` is the array length and `2` the subarray length calling `memcmp (arr+i, subarray, 2)` to check whether the subarray is found beginning at index `i`. Don't invent scenarios not related to the present question. That's a high school level "straw-man" argument.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can not understand how you can misunderstand what you said yourself. But this is not a place for the disussion. Please EOT.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use functions (if you can't see down below):

First, you need a function that checks to see if the current position is a match:

```
int matches_here(int *ArrA, int *ArrB, int sizeB)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizeB;i++)
        if(ArrA[i]!=ArrB[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

This checks each successive element of the two arrays.

Then, you need a function that calls matches_here() at every possible index:

```
int find_subarray(int *ArrA, int sizeA, int *ArrB, int sizeB)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizeA-sizeB+1;i++)
        if(matches_here(&ArrA[i],ArrB,sizeB))
            return i; /* return index */
    return -1; /* not found */
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int ArrA[] = {1,3,5,2,7,6};
    int sizeA = sizeof(ArrA)/sizeof(*ArrA);

    int ArrB[] = {2,7};
    int sizeB = sizeof(ArrB)/sizeof(*ArrB);

    int index=find_subarray(ArrA,sizeA,ArrB,sizeB);
    printf("index=%d\n",index);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/Hk4lTjjSO

If you can't use functions, then this is the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ArrA[] = {1,3,5,2,7,6};
    int sizeA = sizeof(ArrA)/sizeof(*ArrA);
    
    int ArrB[] = {2,7};
    int sizeB = sizeof(ArrB)/sizeof(*ArrB);

    int index = -1;    
    for(int i=0;i<sizeA-sizeB+1;i++)
    {
        // first get a pointer to the starting spot of ArrA
        int *ArrI = &ArrA[i];
        
        // Then check if ArrB matches that part of ArrA
        int found = 1;
        for(int j=0;j<sizeB;j++)
        {
            if(ArrI[j]!=ArrB[j])
            {
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // if it does then we have found it
        if(found == 1)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("index=%d\n",index);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/S16Km_Z8d

Comment: Im sorry if im spamming, im new to stackoverflow, check my message down below.

Comment: Because each function is just called in one place, you can replace the calls with the implementations. It will help you to learn. ;-) -- However, this answer shows in code how a possible algorithm works.

Comment: @thebusybee  I disagree. A function should do one thing - if you stuff everything into one huge function then reasoning about the function is harder - especially when you are trying to learn.  A function with four nested loops is not as easy to understand as two functions each with less complexity.

Comment: Jerry, sorry, I didn't want to address you. You are perfectly right, under normal circumstances. I wanted to address @makisha who said (now deleted) that they have not learned about functions.

Comment: @thebusybee  I didn't see the deleted comment at all.  I guess I should make a version with no functions just to help him out.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @makisha I have added a version without functions.  If there is anything else in the code you don't want to use, let me know.